# Strange results from custom sort function

Tags: c, linux, sorting

I'm trying to create a sort function that takes in a pointer to a dynamically created memory (malloc), the total number of items and the max size of an item.

My current function outputs an alphabetized list, but with the very last result listed in the first position.  I cannot for the life of me, understand what is wrong with the code to cause output like this.

```
int sort_array (char *array, int count, int size)
{
    int i, j;
    char *temp;

    if((temp = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "sort_array: malloc failed\n");
        return(RETURN_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (count * size); i += size)
        for (j = size; j < (count * size); j += size)
            if (strcmp(&array[i], &array[j]) < 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, &array[i]);
                strcpy(&array[i], &array[j]);
                strcpy(&array[j], temp);
            }

    return(RETURN_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output:

```
Zebra
Alpha
Delta
November
Quasar
Start
Van
Window
```

main:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x;
    char *data = NULL;
    char *temp = NULL;
    struct dirent *filename;
    char *path = "/testing/i/m";
    int count = 0;
    DIR *dir;

    if((dir = opendir(path)) != NULL)
    {
        while((filename = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if(filename->d_name[0] != '.')
            {
                if((temp = realloc(data, (count + 1) * FIELD_SIZE * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
                {
                    free(data);
                    fprintf(stderr, "main: realloc failed\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                data = temp;
                strcpy(&data[count++ * FIELD_SIZE], filename->d_name);
            }
        }

        closedir(dir);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "main: unable to read directory contents\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sort_array(data, count, FIELD_SIZE);

    for(x = 0; x < count; x++)
        printf("%s\n", &data[x * FIELD_SIZE]);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the arguments that you passed to the function and how you printed the result to get that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop of your sort routine processes too many items, and moreover appears to apply the wrong order.  To correctly sort in ascending order, this:

```
for (i = 0; i < (count * size); i += size)
    for (j = size; j < (count * size); j += size)
        if (strcmp(&array[i], &array[j]) < 0)
```

should instead be this:

```
for (i = 0; i < (count * size); i += size)
    for (j = i + size; j < (count * size); j += size)
        if (strcmp(&array[i], &array[j]) > 0)
```

Comment: Ty, this was the issue.  I didn't start the inner loop on the first element, because I thought comparing the first element with the first element would be redundant.  My bad.

Comment: Also, I changed the sort order when the results listed were in reverse order with the first item listed last.

Comment: Comparing the first element with itself *would* be redundant.  The modified code does not do that.  In fact, the modification I offered is to ensure that the value at each position `i` (according to the outer loop) is compared only with values in *later* positions (for every i).  You only need to swap when an element that appears *later* than position `i` in the array has a value less than that at position `i`.  The values at earlier positions *should* have lesser values, because they have already been sorted into place.